# How to execute synchronous HTTP requests in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, async-await

I need to execute unknown number of http requests in a node.js program, and it needs to happen synchronously. only when one get the response the next request will be execute. How can I implement that in JS?

**I tried it synchronously with the requset package:**

```js
function HttpHandler(url){

  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
     ...
  })

}

HttpHandler("address-1")
HttpHandler("address-2")
...
HttpHandler("address-100")
```

**And asynchronously with request-promise:**

```js
async function HttpHandler(url){

  const res = await request(url)
  ...

}

HttpHandler("address-1")
HttpHandler("address-2")
...
HttpHandler("address-100")
```

Non of them work. and as I said I can have unknown number of http request over the program, it depends on the end user.

Any ideas on to handle that?

Comment: There is no such thing as synchronous http requests in nodejs (all networking in nodejs is asynchronous).  Do you perhaps mean you need to run them in sequence one after another, even though they are asynchronous?  And, please show what you're trying to do with the responses from these multiple calls as that will effect how the code should be written.  Right now, they don't seem dependent upon one another so they could be run in parallel, without sequencing them in a strict order.

Comment: Also, the `request()` package has been deprecated and is not recommended for new code.  You can pick from a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) which will also make it easier to sequence your calls by using promises and `await`.

Comment: Please don't even try

Comment: @jfriend00 The http requests can be asynchronous, I'm fine with that. I just need the program to be synchronous. for example to get notify when one http got a response and then send the next one, I guess I can use some form of callback, but I'm not sure how to implement that, since I don't have a list of all the requests before runtime. It will be totally dynamic.

Comment: Please show the real logic of your problem so we can offer a complete solution to the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 There is no relevant logic to show, I do nothing with the response. just need the make sure no request will send before the other ends. it's a general question of architecture. It's an easy task in most of the languages, but I can't  find a way to do it in JS.

Comment: Well, it's hard to answer theoretical, non-specific, general questions here.  It often takes 5-10x the work to write a general answer that covers all possibilities.  In the future, you will get faster and more accurate answers if you ask about a real and specific problem, showing the actual code or data you have to work with.  Then, we can focus on your specific situation without any ambiguity about what you're trying to do.  Given you did not do that, I offered a general answer on how to sequence http requests in nodejs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `got()` library, not the `request()` library because the `request()` library has been deprecated and does not support promises.  Then, you can use `async/await` and a `for` loop to sequence your calls one after another.

```
const got = require('got');
let urls = [...];    // some array of urls

async function processUrls(list) {
    for (let url of urls) {
        await got(url);
    }
}

processUrls(urls).then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You are claiming some sort of dynamic list of URLs, but won't show how that works so you'll have to figure out that part of the logic yourself.  I'd be happy to show how to solve that part, but you haven't given us any idea how that should work.

---

If you want a queue that you can regularly add items to, you can do something like this:

```
class sequencedQueue {
    // fn is a function to call on each item in the queue
    // if its asynchronous, it should return a promise
    constructor(fn) {
        this.queue = [];
        this.processing = false;
        this.fn = fn;
    }
    add(...items) {
        this.queue.push(...items);
        return this.run();
    }
    async run() {
        // if not already processing, start processing
        // because of await, this is not a blocking while loop
        while (!this.processing && this.queue.length) {
            try {
                this.processing = true;
                await this.fn(this.queue.shift());
            } catch (e) {
                // need to decide what to do upon error
                // this is currently coded to just log the error and
                // keep processing.  To end processing, throw an error here.
                console.log(e);
            } finally {
                this.processing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also recommend `node-fetch`, as it's compatible with the Fetch API used in browsers, and makes portability a bit easier.

Comment: @Brad - It is a matter of opinion which API to use here.  For programming in nodejs, the `fetch()` API is far, far less convenient than something like `got()` in a number of different ways (streams, parsing of responses, general feature support, etc...).  Sure, if you want compatibility with browser programming, go for node-fetch, but if not, it's not the best option in my opinion.

Comment: That's will work perfectly. but there is one more thing. there are new requests to send all the time. and I know can push them to an array and run through it every X seconds, but I was hoping to find a better way.

Comment: @dev3dev - As I've said multiple times, if you show more of how new urls arrive, I can offer a solution for that, but can't code for something I don't know anything about.  If it's a continuous process, you can use a queue rather than an array (similar concept).  Or run this on all the URLs you have and put any newly arrive urls in a new array.  When this array is done, start processing the array of newly arrived ones.  There are hundreds of ways to do some sort of queue.  You could use a while loop on a queue.  `while (queue not empty) { await got(next queue item) }`

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you. but if I`m getting your example right, so if the queue will become empty once, the while loop will stop, and new URLs that will inserted to the queue will not be handled isn't it?  that's why I thought about setting timer to check every few seconds for a new URLs in the array/queue, but I feel like it's not the right solution. and I'm sorry for not showing the full code, it's 10 files of project and I'm trying to be keep the question as simple as possible .

Comment: @dev3dev - Just make a function that inserts an item into the queue.  In that function, it can check if the queue is empty before inserting into the queue.  If so, after inserting in the queue it will call the function to initiate processing of the queue.  If it's not empty, then it should already be processing and the new one will get picked up when previous ones finish.  You will need a good plan for error handling when running processing like this unattended.  Do you skip errors, retry errors, ignore errors, abort the entire queue upon error, etc...?

Comment: @dev3dev - Don't use timers to check the queue.  Just control access to the queue via functions or class methods so you always know when things are added to the queue and can start processing if not already running.  In an even driven environment like nodejs, you not be polling.

Comment: @dev3dev - We have gone far, far, far beyond what your question ever described or asked.  This is not how to use stackoverflow where you keep diving into more and more of the details of the problem in comments.  You should have more than enough information to start your own implementation.  If you get stuck, write a new question, show your code so far and describe exactly what you got stuck on.  Next time, if you put more detail about exactly what you want from the start into your question and you may get an answer that incorporates more of that.

Comment: @dev3dev - I added an outline for a `sequencedQueue` class.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much. I will try to explain the question in a better way next time.